Difference Between Throwing AuraHandledException and Custom Exception in Apex Aura-Enabled Methods
In Salesforce documentation, it is mentioned that Aura-enabled Apex methods should throw an AuraHandledException to propagate user-friendly error messages to the client. However, I have a custom exception class in my codebase, and I’m curious about the differences in behavior when throwing a custom exception versus an AuraHandledException.
For example:
public class CustomException extends Exception {
}

If I use this custom exception in my code:
throw new CustomException('Something went wrong.');

And compare it with:
throw new AuraHandledException('Something went wrong.');

My Observations :
On the client side, the error body appeared similar in both cases.
However, I noticed a difference in the Apex Debug Logs:
For AuraHandledException, the Status column in the debug logs displayed
"Script-thrown exception."
For CustomException, the Status column displayed the custom error message that was provided when the exception was thrown (e.g., "Something went wrong").
My Question:
What are the key differences in behaviour when using these two types of exceptions in an Aura-enabled Apex method?
I would appreciate examples or explanations regarding the use cases for each approach.

Just curious, what do you mean "On the client side, the error body appeared similar in both cases."?  Are they exactly the same? Or do they have differences? It would be good to understand the differences

One thing to be aware is that if you have a test method that checks the exception's message in an assert, you need to do the following in the code-under-test
String myMessage = 'some message';
AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException(myMessage);
e.setMessage(myMessage);
throw e;

If you do
throw new AuraHandledException(myMessage);

and in the test method you catch the error, this assert will fail
 try {
    myCodeUnderTest.doSomething();
 }
 catch (AuraHandledException e) {
    Assert.areEqual('some message', e.getMessage(), 'msg should be as expected');
  }

Reference

I thought this was the exact reason custom exceptions are "superior" than AuraHandledExceptions since you don't need to explicitly set the message.

They provide same behaviour but AuraHandledException is preferred to use in client side and custom exception is used for specific use cases.
AuraHandledException ensures a user-friendly error message to the client. It is the mostly preferred the error needs to be displayed to the user. And salesforce does the handling for this.
Advised to use: When you need a user-friendly error message to be displayed to the client.
CustomException the client-side catch block may receive a less user-friendly or generic error message, depending on how Salesforce decides to serialize the CustomException.
Advised to use: Use for internal exception handling, business logic, or non-client-facing errors. Let's say you have a object named Object A and is used in apex in many places so using a custom exception for this will be easier to identify for devs too that this exception is related to some issues in Object A.

Do you have any sources to cite that "AuraHandledException is preferred to use in client side and custom exception is used for specific use cases."?
This seems like an opinionated answer, and one that I tend to disagree with.
